# error al ejecutar comando npm start

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

buenas tardes comunidad stackoverflow, hace dias instale node js en su version 12.16.1, para trabajar en react, luego ejecute el comando npm installer -g create-react-app, lo cual funciono bien, luego cree un proyecto mediante el comando create-react-app mi-app, luego ejecute el proyecto y funcionó bien, cuando cerre la consola y probe ejecutar de nuevo el proyecto me da un error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no estarías dentro de la carpeta del proyecto ( el error es que no encuentra package.json que define las dependencias y describe el proyecto )

Comment: no bro, revise bien, no es eso

Comment: es lo que se ve, estas en la carpeta del usuario `edwin` y el error dice textualmente "no encuentro package.json" prueba un `cd mi-app`

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas crear el package.json, puede lograrlo con nmp-init. Situate en el directorio de tu package y ejecuta el comando nmp init. Adjunto una imagen de referencia y un enlace de ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file

Comment: esta bien probare